# Does HyperV allow binding physical NIC on virtual machine with promiscues mode?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, traffic

I have HyperV on Windows 2008 Enterprise R2 installed with some Virtual Server running that I wanted to have ISA or NTOP to monitor traffic.

I've added additional physical NIC to server and wanted to use this NIC as traffic monitor (I've enabled port mirroring on switch).

I can see on physical machine that runs HyperV a lot of traffic coming to the NIC so port mirroring works fine. However in virtual machine even thou I've assigned that NIC to only this one and only server it sees 0 packets.

In VWMare Workstation it worked without problem and I could see mirrored traffic on VM.

Should this be possible or HyperV is crippled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hyper-V does not support promiscuous mode in the guest NICs. See this technet discussion for a little more detail:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/a3c0e8fa-976c-4100-88d7-ceba517d23aa

Comment: Is this still valid for 2012?